# Momentum Operators Constrained to a Hypersphere In Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors, vector-fields

I'm numerically modelling spin-like Fermions on the surface of a (n-1) sphere with equation (x_1)^2+...+(x_n)^2=A^2, where x_1,...,x_n are all real Cartesian coordinates. My wave function looks like $\psi(\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2,...,\vec{v}_k)$, where $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2,...,\vec{v}_k$ are all real vectors in cartesian coordinates that point to the positions of each of the $k$ fermions on the surface of the (n-1) sphere. I want to evaluate a term of the form $\hat{P}_i \cdot \hat{P}_j \psi$ where $\hat{P}_i$ is the momentum operator on the $i$th particle. I have effectively guessed that with the added constraint of being on a (n-1) sphere, that
$\nabla_i \psi \rightarrow (\nabla_i \psi- \hat{r}_i(\nabla_i \psi \cdot \hat{r}_i))=\tilde{\nabla}_i \psi$ and $\nabla_j \cdot f \rightarrow \nabla_j \cdot (f-\hat{r}_j (f \cdot \hat{r}_j))=\tilde{\nabla}_j \cdot f$. By taking $\hat{P}_i \sim \tilde{\nabla}_i$ then, I appear to be getting the correct result for terms like $\hat{P}_i \cdot \hat{P}_j \psi$ with $i=j$, but not terms with $i\neq j$. What should $\hat{P}_i \cdot \hat{P}_j \psi$ be given the constraint that the particles must remain on the (n-1) sphere? I am quite contained to use Cartesian co-ordinates as changing this and going to other coordinates would require me to almost completely rewrite my program.